# How to run SonarQube Scanner with Gradle MSBuild Plugin?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gradle, automation, sonarqube

I am using the MSBuild plugin for Gradle (https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-msbuild-plugin) to build my C++ project under Windows, this works fine.  I couldn't find a way to run SonarQube Scanner Build Wrapper (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Building+on+Windows) with it though, which is necessary for C/C++ projects.

The `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id "com.ullink.msbuild" version "3.1"
}
...
msbuild {
    projectFile = file("${buildDir}/${Target_platform_arch}/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj")

    projectName = 'SomeProject'

    verbosity = 'detailed'

    targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']

    version = '14.0'

    msbuildDir = /path/to/Msbuild
    ...
}
```

The sonarqube scanner build wrapper supposed to be called as:

```
build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir bw_output MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
```

So how do I run the build-wrapper together with the Gradle MSBuild plugin? I thought this usecase is not a rare one, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried running: `build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir bw_output gradle <your build task>` ?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam yeah that actually works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build wrapper is intercepting low level compiler calls so it can in theory work with any build framework.

If you are using Gradle to build a C/C++ project, simply call:

```
build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir bw_output gradle <your build task>
```